# How to prove the inequalities between $20^{70^2},30^{60^2},40^{50^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let $$M=\{ 20^{70^2}, 30^{60^2},40^{50^2}\}$$.
What number is the greatest and which is the smallest?

I thought about beginning by assuming certain inequalities and trying to prove them, for example: $$20^{70^2} < 30^{60^2}$$
However, I do not know exactly what do from here. I took logarithms and expanded the expressions, this took me nowhere. I could get no obvious identity out of them, is there a clever way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A good start is to notice all three inequalities have the form
$$
f(x) = x^{(90-x)^2}
$$
So what you want is the order of $f(20), f(30), f(40)$.
Rather than comparing the numbers directly, it's a good idea to get rid of nested exponentials by taking logarithms.
We can set
$$
g(x) = \ln \ln f(x) = \ln \left[ (90-x)^2 \ln x\right]
= 2 \ln (90-x) + \ln \ln x
$$
Now we have an intuitive answer: $\ln \ln x$ is a VERY slow-growing function and won't change too much from $20$ to $40$, while on the other hand $\ln(90-x)$ will get a bit smaller.
So we expect $g(20) > g(30) > g(40)$, and therefore $f(20) > f(30) > f(40)$.

To actually prove this, we can use calculus to show $g$ is decreasing on the interval $[20,40]$. We have
\begin{align*}
g'(x)
&= \frac{-2}{90-x} + \frac{1}{x \ln x}\\
&= \frac{1}{x(90-x)\ln x} \left( 90-x - 2x\ln x\right)
\end{align*}
and for $x\ge 20$, $\ln x > 2$ so
\begin{align*}
90 - x - 2x \ln x
  &< 90 - (20) - 2(20)(2) \\
  &= -10 \\
  &< 0.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 5):

It is enough to switch to logarithms and consider that:

$$ \frac{9}{13}<\log 2<\frac{7}{10},\qquad \frac{78}{71}<\log 3<\frac{11}{10},\qquad \frac{23}{10}<\log(10)<\frac{76}{33}.$$
With crude estimations $70^2\log(20)\approx 14000$, $60^2\log 30\approx 12000$ and $50^2\log(40)\approx 9000$.

A more elegant approach is to study the function $f(x)=x^2\log(90-x)$ over the interval $(0,90)$ and prove that its relative maximum is located at $x_0>70$, so $f(x)$ is increasing on $(0,70]$.

Comment: Damn, that's a hella elegant solution

Answer (score 3):

For a more elementary approach: you could play around with the factors.
$$20^{70^2} = 2^{4900} \cdot 10^{4900} = 32^{980}  \cdot 10^{1300}\cdot 10^{3600}, $$
$$30^{60^2} = 3^{3600} \cdot 10^{3600} = 27^{980} \cdot 3^{660} \cdot 10^{3600}.$$
Comparing each factor, it is now obvious that $20^{70^2} > 30^{60^2}$.

Similarly,
$$30^{60^2} = 3^{3600} \cdot 10^{3600} = 3^{268} \cdot 3^{3332} \cdot 10^{1100}\cdot 10^{2500} = 3^{268} \cdot 9^{1666} \cdot 10^{1100}\cdot 10^{2500},$$
$$40^{50^2} = 4^{2500} \cdot 10^{2500} = 2^{5000} \cdot 10^{2500} = 2 \cdot 8^{1666} \cdot 10^{2500},$$
hence $30^{60^2} > 40^{50^2}$.

The trick here is always to find powers of $2$ and $3$ with small difference: $2^5 > 3^3$ and $2^3 < 3^2$.

Comment: +1, a nice approach! With numbers that differ by such large margins, we sometimes forget that we can be really not careful with our inequalities and just roughly compare things and the proof still goes through.

Answer (score 2):

Compare
$$
20^{4900} \mbox{ and } 30^{3600} \mbox{ and } 40^{2500};
$$
i.e.
$$
(20^{49})^{100} \mbox{ and } (30^{36})^{100} \mbox { and } (40^{25})^{100};
$$
therefore there is enough to compare
$$
20^{49} \mbox{ and } 30^{36} \mbox { and } 40^{25};
$$
i.e.
$$
2^{49}\cdot 10^{49} \mbox{ and } 3^{36}\cdot 10^{36} \mbox { and } 4^{25}\cdot 10^{25};
$$
and (dividing by $10^{36}$)
$$
\color{red}{2^{49}\cdot 10^{13}} \mbox{ and } 
\color{green}{3^{36}} \mbox { and } 
\color{blue}{4^{25} / 10^{11}}.
$$

Now,

$\color{green}{3^{36}} = 9^{18} = 9^5 \cdot 9^{13} < 16^5 \cdot 10^{13} = 2^{20} \cdot 10^{13} \color{red}{< 2^{49}\cdot 10^{13}}$;

and

$\color{green}{3^{36}} = 3^{28}\cdot 3^8 = 9^{14}\cdot 3^8 \color{blue}{> 4^{14} \cdot (4/10)^{11}}$;

hence

$$
20^{70^2}> 30^{60^2} > 40^{50^2}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$40=30^a \;$ where $$a=[\ln(40]/\ln 30=1+[\ln (1+1/3)]/\ln 30<1+[1/3]/\ln 30<1+1/9.$$ Therefore  $\quad 40^{50^2}=30^{a\cdot  50^2}<30^{(1+1/9)50^2}<30^{60^2}.$

$30=20^b \;$ where $$b=[\ln 30]/\ln 20=1+[\ln (1+1/2)]/\ln 20<1+[1/2]/\ln 20<1+1/4.$$ Therefore $\quad 30^{60^2}=20^{b\cdot 60^2}<20^{(1+1/4)60^2}<20^{70^2}.$

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, to get a sense of the size of $a^b$, $b$ matters much more. This isn't a general rule though. But considering decreasing the exponent $70^2$ to $60^2$ versus increasing $20$ to $30$, the former is a greater reduction, especially given that it is an exponent, one would intuitively expect $20^{70^2}>30^{60^2}$. But again, this reasoning will not always hold.

This answer is probably not very appropriate in this context, but I will post it anyways since someone might find it interesting or useful. Even some precalculus students may find it helpful to developing a deeper intuitive understanding.

More generally, consider $(A+k)^{B^2}$ vs $A^{{(B+k)}^2}$. Taking logarithms we get that $(A+k)^{B^2}<A^{{(B+k)}^2}$ when

$$
\frac{\ln(A+k)}{\ln A}<\frac{(B+k)^2}{B^2}.
$$

Given that quadratic growth is faster than logarithmic growth, we should expect the relative growth (percentage increase) from $B^2$ to $(B+k)^2$ to be greater than that from $\ln A$ to $\ln (A+k)$ unless $B$ is very large relative to $A$ and $k$ is relatively small.

This occurs because $B^2$ is already going to be a very large number, so increasing $B$ by a sufficiently small $k$ doesn't result in much of a percentage increase. However, if $A$ is sufficiently small, increasing $A$ by $k$ can result in a larger percentage increase in the logarithmic function.

For $A=20$ and $k=10$, we need around $B>152$ in order to reverse the above inequality.

A similar argument will hold for powers other than $2$, say $(A+k)^{B^n}$ vs $A^{{(B+k)}^n}$ since power growth is always faster than logarithmic growth. For a fixed $A$ and $k$, a larger power requires a larger $B$  to reverse the expected/intuitive inequality given above.

Answer (score 1):

$20^{70^2} = 20^{70^2}$

$30^{60^2} = 1.5^{60^2}20^{60^2}$

$40^{50^2} = 2^{50^2}20^{50^2}$

=====

$20^{70^2-60^2}=20^{10*130}=20^{1300} $

$1.5^{60^2}=2.25^{30*60}=5.0625^{90}$

$2^{50^2}20^{50^2-60^2}=2^{2500}2^{-10*110}10^{-1100} =2^{1400}10^{-1100}=2^{300}5^{-1100}>5^{-800}$

======

So $40^{50^2}<30^{60^2}<20^{70^2} $ and by fairly significant margins.

Comment: It's a nice sort of straightforward way of trudging through it. But the answer is wrong, so there must be a mistake.

Comment: The mistake is $40^{50^2} \ne 20^{2 \cdot 50^2}$, because $40 \ne 20^2$.

Comment: Dammit.  You're right.  That I did get a different answer the first time I did it when I used 10 as my base should have tipped me off.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a strange way to view it but bear with me:

Obviously if $0< a < b; x < y$ then $a^x < b^y$ but we should develop an intuition for when $0 < a < b; x >y$ how to compare $a^x$ to $b^y$.

Let $b = k*a; k > 1$ so $ a < b$.  Let $x = my; m > 1$ so $x >y$.

Then $a^x <|=|> b^y \iff$

$\frac{a^x}{b^y} = \frac{a^{my}}{a^yk^y} <|=|> 1 \iff$

$a^{(m-1)y} <|=|> k^y \iff a^{m-1} <|=|> k$

So $20^{70^2} <|=|> 30^{60^2} \iff 20^{\frac 76^2 - 1} <|=|> 1.5$

As $20^{13/36}>20^{1/3} > 8^{1/3} = 2 > 1.5$ we have $20^{70^2} > 30^{60^2}$

Likewise $30^{60^2} <|=|> 40^{50^2} \iff 30^{\frac 65^2 - 1} <|=|> 1\frac 13$.

As $30^{11/25} > 30^{2/5} = 900^{1/5} > 32^{1/5} = 2 > 1 \frac 13$ so $30^{60^2} > 40^{50^2}$

In general, we should develop the intuition that increases in exponents are ...er,  exponentially .. more significant than increases in bases.